# Bootstrap col-lg lower width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Maybe easy to asnwer but is there a way for instance when using col-lg-1 this column to have lower width? I am asking because i have some column with numbers like on below picture:

[image]

As you see there is still lot place of width which could be consume by next column. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Try mixing your own Bootstrap recipe: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: can you give some code proposition?

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap doesn't offer this option. It has a 12 columns grid layout.
If you are using SASS, I suggest you use [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/), it's a responsive layout toolkit.

Comment: Not true. You can create a custom grid layout using Bootstrap's own 'Customise' option: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: I don't think @JohnDoe needs a grid refactory but rather a solution for the specific case explained in his question.